# Capture between two substrings with regular expressions

Tags: regex

This is probably really easy.

But I want to write a regular expression that starts at the word "DISTINCTION" and then ends directly before the word "Distinction" begins again (See the data below).

My current regular expression is this (DIST[^DIST]*) but of course this finds a match whenever the engine finds "D", "I", "S", or "T". So I can make the search stop only when it finds "DIST"? Thanks for your help.

The data looks like this:

> DISTINCTION XLII
>
> Chapter I:  On the Omnipotence of God, for what reason is He said to
>   be “omnipotent”, since we can do many things, which He Himself cannot
>   do. Chapter II:  In what manner is God said to be able to do all
>   things. Chapter III:  That the Omnipotence of God is considered
>   according to two acts.
>
> DISTINCTION XLIII
>
> Chapter I:  An invective against those who say, that God can do
>   nothing, but what He wills and does.
>
> DISTINCTION XLIV
>
> Chapter I:  Whether God can make something better, than He has made
>   it, and/or in another and/or better manner, than He has. Chapter II: 
>   Whether God can always do everything which He could do.
>
> DISTINCTION XLV

Comment: You might find lookarounds (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) helpful.

Comment: does this really require a look around? Isn't there away to see "DIST" as "D and I and S and T" rather than "D or I or S or T"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
DIST(?:(?!DIST).)*
```

matches from `DIST` up until the position before the next `DIST` (or the end of the string if there isn't one). Make sure you set the "dot-matches-all" option (details vary with your regex engine).

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/eF0bV9).

**Explanation:**

```
DIST      # Match "DIST".
(?:       # Start a group that matches...
 (?!DIST) # (unless we're at the start of the word "DIST")
 .        # any character.
)*        # Repeat as needed.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/DISTINCTION(.*?)DISTINCTION/
```

or

```
/DISTINCTION([^(DISTINCTION)]*?)DISTINCTION/
```

Comment: `[^(DISTINCTION)]` means "any character except `(`, `D`, `I`, `S`, `T`, `N`, `C`, `O` or `)`". Also, this regex will only find every other match, and it will never find the final match.

Comment: Parens do not create capture groups inside of a character class; they're matched literally.